# Return the index of the last occurrence of a string in a column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want change this formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("DONE";B$1:B3;0);IF((DATEDIF($A$4;$A4;"D")) < B$2;"TODO";"LATER"))
```

To solve the problem with the cells `B30`, `B31`, `B32` and `B33`.

[image: 0]

I want that the cells `B30`, `B31`, `B32` and `B33` returns the line with the last occurrence of the `DONE` string and no the first one.

Comment: any additional explanation would be welcome coz so far it doesn't make any sense what you are after

Comment: @ScottCraner the MATCH formula exists in excel and in google-sheets, but i'm working with google-sheets.

Comment: @player0 why does not any sense?

Comment: @player0 I add some explanation.

Comment: @FabianoLothor but as you can see the MATCH formula will not work for what you want.  To do this in Excel I would use AGGREGATE() which does not exist in Google Sheets

Comment: @fabianolothor what is the problem? what exactly to you want to achieve, aside from the screen cap you gave?

Comment: It might be a good idea to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55619291/edit) to clarify it

Comment: @Sirmyself the cells B30, B31, B32 and B33 needs returns `29` and no `7`.

Comment: @fabianolothor why do they need to return 29? that's the kind of thing that would be useful to add to your question EDIT - *I see you added those details*

Comment: But you can use `=ArrayFormula(Large(If($B$1:B3 = "DONE",ROW($B$1:B3)),1))` in place of the match.

Comment: @Sirmyself because i need of the last occurrence of the `DONE` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(B3="DONE", 
 MAX(FILTER(ROW(A$1:A3), B$1:B3="DONE")),
 MAX(FILTER(ROW(A$1:A3), B$1:B3="DONE"))),
 IF(DATEDIF(A$4, A4, "D") < B$2, "TODO", "LATER"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It's done: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hk1RoBEf44bWhV72ZcXZvueeDqwIGKcEx7-VfmFshYk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for the help! I make it with the @ScottCraner solution.